# page url as a variable to use in plugins

Tags: php

i have a cms which creates pages in the form of index.php?p=PAGENAME
for example:

```
index.php?p=01Home
index.php?p=news
index.php?p=about
```

or whatever pagename

now what i want to do is to get the PAGENAME as a variable

for example

```
$page="01home";
$page="news";
$page="about";
```

i tried to get the pagename via $_GET[p] from my cms code, but that doesnt work, any other ideas? The code must be independent from the cms so i can use the pagename in a plugin

PLUGIN code where i want o use the pagename

```
<?php  
  $amount= $cfr ;
  $page = $_GET['p'];
  if (!isset($_GET["action"])) {
    }
elseif ($_GET["action"] == "write") // etc.
{

     header('location: succes.php');
    $data = ''.PHP_EOL;
    $file=fopen("plugins/comments/comments/$page/comments.txt",'a');

    $message=str_replace("\r",'',$message);
    $message=str_replace("\n",'{{',$_GET['message']);
    fwrite($file,$_GET['name'].'||'.date('d-m-Y').'||'.$message.$data);
    fclose($file);

  }
  $start=(isset($_GET['start'])?$_GET['start']:0);
  $gastenboek=Array();
  $gastenboek=file("plugins/comments/comments/$page/comments.txt");

?>
<br>
<fieldset class="comments">
  <legend class="pm">Reacties</legend>
<div style="float:right;">Aantal reacties: <b><?php echo min($start+$amount,sizeof($gastenboek)); ?></b></div>
            <TABLE class="comments" width="100%">
          <?PHP
          $gastenboek=array_reverse($gastenboek);
          for ($i=$start;$i<$start+$amount && $i<sizeof($gastenboek);$i++) {
            list($name,$date,$message)=explode('||',$gastenboek[$i]);
            $message=str_replace('{{',"\n",$message);
            echo '<TR><TD class="comments"><div style="float:left;">
<B>'.$name.'</B></div><div style="float:right;">
(<i>'.$date.'</i>)</div><br><p>'.str_replace("\n",'<BR>',htmlspecialchars($message)).'</p>  </TD></TR>'."\n";
                                     }
        ?>
        </TABLE>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset class="pm">
  <legend class="pm">Plaats een reactie</legend>
 <FORM action="index.php" method="GET" onSubmit="return validate(this);" name="comments" id="comments">
              <INPUT type="hidden" name="action" value="write">
              <p class="pm">Naam: </p> 
              <INPUT type="text" name="name" size="30" style="width:300px;" required><br>
              <p class="pm2">Reactie: </p> 

            <TEXTAREA class="message" name="message" id="message" cols="46" rows="5" required></TEXTAREA><br>

          <INPUT type="submit" value="Reactie toevoegen">
        </FORM>
</fieldset>            
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $('#comments').ebcaptchaword();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: use $_GET["p"] for the page name.

Comment: just try to find out which variable is use for copying ($_GET['p']) then change it, or try to reset $_GET['p'] like `$_GET['p'] ='about'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url being - `index.php?p=01Home`
Try this -

```
$page = $_GET['p'];
```

Comment: i tried that, as i menion in my question, bu that doesnt seem to work

Comment: you tried $_GET['page'] instead of $_GET['p']. I believe the answer is accurate just add ";" in the end.

Comment: @user3090697 I don't understand. It should work for the above url types.

Comment: @user3090697 Did you try echoing the $page after assigning it?

Comment: Probably, you are overwriting the $page variable somewhere. Wherever you are using the variable, try echoing it. That might help you to find the place where it is overwritten

Answer (score 0):

If it says ?p=pagename that should mean you should use $_GET['p']... or I'm not getting this problem right.

Comment: indeed, but via $_GET[p] I get $page = 5thumbs